# When a Conversation is deleted, are the Messages in the conversation also deleted, or do I have to explicitly delete each message?

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

When tearing down a Conversation, I am:

1. Removing the Participant from the Conversation (Participant.Delete)
2. Deleting the User (UserResource.Delete)
3. Deleting the Conversation (ConversationResource.Delete)

Are the messages (IMXXX...) in the Conversation automatically deleted when the Conversation is deleted, or should I step through each Message and delete it before deleting the Conversation (MessageResource.Delete)?

I can't manually verify whether the Messages are deleted since after deleting the Conversation I can't return to the Conversation in the Console to see if the messages are still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with the Conversations team and deleting a Conversation resource will cascade and delete the associated messages.

I will look into getting this documented so others can see this in the future.

Comment: Thanks, Phil. I appreciate your availability and quick responses.